# Counting occurrence of non-specified values from 2d array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I've got a similar array:

```
[['foo', 9283], ['bar', 7172], ['bar', 9890], ['foo', 2291], ['fuubar', 8291]]
```

I want to count the same values in `list[i][0]`, without specifying what string I want to find. Examples I've found on the Internet are either about 1D arrays or with specification. If I had a 1D array that would be extremely simple:
**Example 1 with specifying the value (1)**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1].count(1)
3
```

**Example 2 without specyifying what to look for**

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> z = ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
>>> Counter(z)
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'yellow': 1})
```

My desired output would be similar. Given my example, I want to know how many times does 'foo' occur, 'bar' occurs, 'fuubar' occurs. But how do I do this with a 2D array?

Comment: Note that `0091` is not a valid literal anymore. It used to be a literal octal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generator expression to extract the items you want to count:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [['foo', 9283], ['bar', 7172], ['bar', 9890], ['foo', 91], ['fuubar', 8291]]
>>> Counter(item[0] for item in l)
Counter({'foo': 2, 'bar': 2, 'fuubar': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Counter([z[0] for z in [['foo', 9283], ['bar', 7172], ['bar', 9890], ['foo', 91], ['fuubar', 8291]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack:

```
Counter(s for s, _ in l))
```

Or for a functional approach:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(Counter(map(itemgetter(0), l)))
```